# How to use Objective-C's TargetConditionals.h in an assembly file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, assembly, x86, arm

I have a library that is linked into both ARM and x86 code.
The library contains assembly files, some of which are for ARM and some for x86.
One solution for that is to create two targets, one for ARM and one for x86.
The rest of the code uses TargetConditionals.h to differentiate the architecture, so I wouldn't want to split the target unless it is necessary.
Is it possible to use TargetConditionals.h in an assembly file? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

```
#if defined(__arm64__)
#if defined(__x86_64__)
```